# How do I cut one mesh with other mesh and join them?

Tags: modeling

I have here two meshes, I am trying to cut the sphere surface with the other mesh and join their faces like if it was an extrusion. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

I'm a beginner at this. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: boolean modifier with "union" may work here, if I understand you well. If I see well, you'll need to separate it in 2 meshes before using the modifier

Comment: Have you tried a boolean modifier? Choose the sphere, add a boolean modifier, set the object to the other mesh. And select union (then turn off visibility of the original meshes). That should join the 2 meshes. Although the result won't be pretty. Ideally, you should model this connection by hand to get good geometry.